# detect click into iframe using angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, iframe, primeng

I want to close multi-select drop-down popup when user click outside the popup. It's working fine when user click outside of IFrame. But when user click on iframe  popup did't got closed. I am trying to add some patch code but for that I need to detect click event on Iframe. I seen too many example but did't got fine solution.

```
 @HostListener('click', ['$event.target'])
  onClick() {
    console.log('iframe clicked');
 }
```

I have tried above code but onClick method didn't call on iframe click.

Note: I need to detect every click event not only first click.

Comment: You can't. The event occurs inside the iframe window instance not in parent window

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this Angular directive:

```
import {
  Directive,
  ElementRef,
  OnInit,
  Renderer2,
  Input,
  Output,
  EventEmitter,
  HostListener
} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appIframeTracker]'
})
export class IframeTrackerDirective implements OnInit {
  private iframeMouseOver: boolean;

  @Input() debug: boolean;

  @Output() iframeClick = new EventEmitter<ElementRef>();

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.renderer.listen(window, 'blur', () => this.onWindowBlur());
  }

  @HostListener('mouseover')
  private onIframeMouseOver() {
    this.log('Iframe mouse over');
    this.iframeMouseOver = true;
    this.resetFocusOnWindow();
  }

  @HostListener('mouseout')
  private onIframeMouseOut() {
    this.log('Iframe mouse out');
    this.iframeMouseOver = false;
    this.resetFocusOnWindow();
  }

  private onWindowBlur() {
    if (this.iframeMouseOver) {
      this.log('WOW! Iframe click!!!');
      this.resetFocusOnWindow();
      this.iframeClick.emit(this.el);
    }
  }

  private resetFocusOnWindow() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.log('reset focus to window');
      window.focus();
    }, 100);
  }

  private log(message: string) {
    if (this.debug) {
      console.log(message);
    }
  }
}
```

It emits an output event when we click on IFrame.

Source: https://gist.github.com/micdenny/db03a814eaf4cd8abf95f77885d9316f

I hope it will help.

Comment: As per my under standing it will call every time when mouse hover on iframe. But in my case I need to close multi-select popup on click event.