# detect events from external iframe

Tags: javascript, html, angular, iframe

Inside my Angular 11 App, I'm opening an iframe that is rendering another external website

I just want to detect mouse events like click, touch and scroll for example when they happen inside the iframe, so I can react accordingly in my App, but I'm not able to do that

I tried the solution suggested here:
[detect click into iframe using angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57309735/detect-click-into-iframe-using-angular)

but that is preventing me from interacting with inputs inside the iframe, and it's not working with the touch event also.

Also **window.parent.postMessage** is not an option since that website is external.